# bxSlider plugin not loading the classes

Tags: php, jquery

I am using bxSlider plugin on my site it is working fine on my local machine but on my staging server it is not working the problem is i think it is not loading the classes because I cant see the bx-wrapper, bx-window etc classes on my staging server while these class comes on my local machine.
The jquery.bxSlider.min.js is there in js folder on staging server
Anyone has any idea why its not working ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should check the source code to make sure that jquery and the plugin files are actually loaded correctly.

Comment: I checked it even in source code in my head tag the bxslider script is loaded

Comment: You should check console in for example firebug to see if it gives you an error. ..and are you sure you checked the source code for the files that are online?

Comment: it says #slider1 is not a function

Comment: Are you sure that the files you have online are exactly the same as the ones you have locally? And _'working'_ example of the code/site thats giving you problems is always super helpful.

Comment: yes I am damn sure let me upload them again from my local machine

Comment: still not working though i uploaded files from my local machine :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9898/discussion-between-lollero-and-faryal-khan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be extra/older jquery file being loaded in, which seemed to screw up the code.